# Fonte customizada React Native

Tags: arquivo, react-native, importação, font

Estou com muita dificuldade de para adicionar uma fonte no meu projeto React Native. Já tentei com muitos tutoriais mas nenhum se encaixa bem no meu caso, e vários não funcionam.

Aqui é onde defino meu componente já estilizado (Que vou chamar de Arquivo1.JS)

```
import styled from 'styled-components/native';

export const Title = styled.Text`
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #444;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
`;
```

Aqui é onde uso o componente que defini acima (Que vou chamar de Arquivo2.JS)

```
import {Title} from '../Arquivo1.JS';

export default function Login() {

  return (    

            <Title> Teste </Title>  

         );

}
```

Está anexado no post minha estrutura de pastas, e a pasta com minhas fontes

[image: Minha estrutura de pastas]
Se alguém souber e puder me ajudar ficarei grato.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amigo para inserir fontes/icones personalizadas é necessário criar um arquivo chamado de "react-native.config.js" na raiz do projeto passando o seguinte código:

**RN 6.0+**

```
module.exports = {
  project: {
    ios: {},
    android: {},
  },
  assets: ['./src/assets/fonts/', './src/assets/icons/'],
};
```

**Depois rode os comando**

```
react-native link
react-native run-ios ou react-native run-android
```

Na propriedade assets passe o caminho da suas fontes e icones.

Depois é necessário rodar o comando react-native run-io ou react-native run-android pois as fontes devem ser importadas dentro do projeto nativo. Se mesmo assim a fonte/icone não importou tente importar conforme o tutorial:
https://medium.com/better-programming/using-custom-fonts-in-react-native-2019-289099609837

Depois para usar basta passar o nome da fonte no style na propriedade fontFamily.

**Ex:**

```
style = {
  fontFamily: "Roboto"
}
```

Ou com Styled Components

```
import styled from 'styled-components/native';

export const Title = styled.Text`
  font-family: 'Roboto'
`;
```

Comment: Valeu cara, ajudou demais!!!

Comment: Que bom que te ajudou ! Por nada :)